# Indexing into a Dictionary and Iterating in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, binary-search-tree

I am indexing a large CSV (5000+ lines) file into Python using the following code:

```
index = {}
df = open('file.csv', encoding='UTF-8')

fp = 0
l = df.readline()
while l:
    r = l.split(',')
    index[r[0]] = fp
    fp = df.tell()
    l = df.readline()
df.seek(index["Sarah"])
print(df.readline())
df.close()
```

Here is an example of the file content:

```
John, Always wears a blue hat
Alex, Always wears a red shirt
Sarah, Hates the colour pink
```

Here is an example of how they have been indexed:

```
{'John': 26389, 'Alex': 217059, 'Sarah': 142108...}
```

I am trying to add the indexed data into a binary search tree I've built using a tutorial on interactivepython. Here is the BST:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self,key,val,left=None,right=None,parent=None):
        self.key = key
        self.payload = val
        self.leftChild = left
        self.rightChild = right
        self.parent = parent

    def hasLeftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild

    def hasRightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

    def isLeftChild(self):
        return self.parent and self.parent.leftChild == self

    def isRightChild(self):
        return self.parent and self.parent.rightChild == self

    def isRoot(self):
        return not self.parent

    def isLeaf(self):
        return not (self.rightChild or self.leftChild)

    def hasAnyChildren(self):
        return self.rightChild or self.leftChild

    def hasBothChildren(self):
        return self.rightChild and self.leftChild

    def replaceNodeData(self,key,value,lc,rc):
        self.key = key
        self.payload = value
        self.leftChild = lc
        self.rightChild = rc
        if self.hasLeftChild():
            self.leftChild.parent = self
        if self.hasRightChild():
            self.rightChild.parent = self


class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def length(self):
        return self.size

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def put(self,key,val):
        if self.root:
            self._put(key,val,self.root)
        else:
            self.root = TreeNode(key,val)
        self.size = self.size + 1

    def _put(self,key,val,currentNode):
        if key < currentNode.key:
            if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
                   self._put(key,val,currentNode.leftChild)
            else:
                   currentNode.leftChild = TreeNode(key,val,parent=currentNode)
        else:
            if currentNode.hasRightChild():
                   self._put(key,val,currentNode.rightChild)
            else:
                   currentNode.rightChild = TreeNode(key,val,parent=currentNode)

    def __setitem__(self,k,v):
       self.put(k,v)

    def get(self,key):
       if self.root:
           res = self._get(key,self.root)
           if res:
                  return res.payload
           else:
                  return None
       else:
           return None

    def _get(self,key,currentNode):
       if not currentNode:
           return None
       elif currentNode.key == key:
           return currentNode
       elif key < currentNode.key:
           return self._get(key,currentNode.leftChild)
       else:
           return self._get(key,currentNode.rightChild)

    def __getitem__(self,key):
       return self.get(key)

    def __contains__(self,key):
       if self._get(key,self.root):
           return True
       else:
           return False

    def delete(self,key):
      if self.size > 1:
         nodeToRemove = self._get(key,self.root)
         if nodeToRemove:
             self.remove(nodeToRemove)
             self.size = self.size-1
         else:
             raise KeyError('Error, key not in tree')
      elif self.size == 1 and self.root.key == key:
         self.root = None
         self.size = self.size - 1
      else:
         raise KeyError('Error, key not in tree')

    def __delitem__(self,key):
       self.delete(key)

    def spliceOut(self):
       if self.isLeaf():
           if self.isLeftChild():
                  self.parent.leftChild = None
           else:
                  self.parent.rightChild = None
       elif self.hasAnyChildren():
           if self.hasLeftChild():
                  if self.isLeftChild():
                     self.parent.leftChild = self.leftChild
                  else:
                     self.parent.rightChild = self.leftChild
                  self.leftChild.parent = self.parent
           else:
                  if self.isLeftChild():
                     self.parent.leftChild = self.rightChild
                  else:
                     self.parent.rightChild = self.rightChild
                  self.rightChild.parent = self.parent

    def findSuccessor(self):
      succ = None
      if self.hasRightChild():
          succ = self.rightChild.findMin()
      else:
          if self.parent:
                 if self.isLeftChild():
                     succ = self.parent
                 else:
                     self.parent.rightChild = None
                     succ = self.parent.findSuccessor()
                     self.parent.rightChild = self
      return succ

    def findMin(self):
      current = self
      while current.hasLeftChild():
          current = current.leftChild
      return current

    def remove(self,currentNode):
         if currentNode.isLeaf(): #leaf
           if currentNode == currentNode.parent.leftChild:
               currentNode.parent.leftChild = None
           else:
               currentNode.parent.rightChild = None
         elif currentNode.hasBothChildren(): #interior
           succ = currentNode.findSuccessor()
           succ.spliceOut()
           currentNode.key = succ.key
           currentNode.payload = succ.payload

         else: # this node has one child
           if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
             if currentNode.isLeftChild():
                 currentNode.leftChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                 currentNode.parent.leftChild = currentNode.leftChild
             elif currentNode.isRightChild():
                 currentNode.leftChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                 currentNode.parent.rightChild = currentNode.leftChild
             else:
                 currentNode.replaceNodeData(currentNode.leftChild.key,
                                    currentNode.leftChild.payload,
                                    currentNode.leftChild.leftChild,
                                    currentNode.leftChild.rightChild)
           else:
             if currentNode.isLeftChild():
                 currentNode.rightChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                 currentNode.parent.leftChild = currentNode.rightChild
             elif currentNode.isRightChild():
                 currentNode.rightChild.parent = currentNode.parent
                 currentNode.parent.rightChild = currentNode.rightChild
             else:
                 currentNode.replaceNodeData(currentNode.rightChild.key,
                                    currentNode.rightChild.payload,
                                    currentNode.rightChild.leftChild,
                                    currentNode.rightChild.rightChild)
```

I can add individual items using the command:

```
mytree = BinarySearchTree()
mytree[1] = "One"
```

What I am trying to do is iterate over the index dictionary but I keep getting an error.

Here is how I am iterating over the dictionary:

```
for k, v in index.items():
    mytree[k] = v
```

Comment: full stacktrace please.

Comment: Thanks for replying. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm going out on a limb and guessing this is the line with the error: `if key < currentNode.key:`?

Comment: @leaf I wouldn't take the time to read through the wall of code. Must be it!

Comment: @128K copy/paste the text _before_ the error message. It points to the location of the error & callers.

Comment: Could you please explain why? I don't understand why that is causing a problem.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I have added it to the bottom of the question.

Comment: because `key` is probably a string and the other term is an integer. You cannot compare those types with python 3. `key` would be `'John'` or something. Can you print the terms before comparison?

Comment: @128K I can't say for sure, but I'm guessing `key` is a string and `currentNode.key` is a integer. In that case, you need to convert `key` to an integer as well: `if int(key) < currentNode.key:`.

Comment: @leaf: great divination powers :) however I didn't see integer to string conversion.

Comment: The key is a word and the indexing makes the value a number. So the key is the persons name and the value is a description of sometime which has been indexed. Like so:
`{John: Always wears a blue hat}` indexed as `John:18239` where `18239` is the position in the CSV file

Comment: @128K So if `key` and `currentNode.key` are names, what exactly are you trying to test with `if key < currentNode.key:`? Are you trying to compare the lengths of each name?

Comment: @leaf: ordering them alphabetically, presumably.

Comment: I am ordering alphabetically yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you mean to do is to add the elements in the binary tree based on their csv position. If so, then try adding the element based on their value (instead of the key).

```
for k, v in index.items():
    mytree[v] = k
```

EDIT: Based on the comments, it looks like the OP is trying to enter the elements in the tree based on their names (and not values). In order to catch which key value pair is causing this exception, how about adding this code? This would atleast narrow down the issue to the specific key-value pair causing this exception. One possibility is that the key in some cases is a string and in other cases might be a int (just a guess!)

```
def _put(self,key,val,currentNode):
    try:
        if key < currentNode.key:
            if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
               self._put(key,val,currentNode.leftChild)
            else:
               currentNode.leftChild = TreeNode(key,val,parent=currentNode)
        else:
            if currentNode.hasRightChild():
               self._put(key,val,currentNode.rightChild)
            else:
               currentNode.rightChild = TreeNode(key,val,parent=currentNode)
    except TypeError as e:
        print "key = ", key
        print "currentNode key = ", currentNode.key
        print "val = ", val
        raise e
```

Comment: That works to get the data into the binary tree but I cannot search it by name this way, or can I?

Comment: If you want to look for something by name, use dict.

Comment: It is in a dictionary before it is added to the BST using the following format `{name: index number in csv}` If I import it to the BST using the Value instead of the key, I cannot search the BST using the key can I?

Comment: As far as I can see it will work, just not this statement.

Comment: Could you please recommend a statement that will work so I can start to learn searching etc.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error as soon as some of the keys are ints and some are strings, they aren't comparable so that's not going to work.

Did you actually use the line

```
ytree[1] = "One"
```

? Because that uses an int key, and the rest of the code inserts strings as keys. It should have been the other way around.

Comment: is there a more appropriate way to use index of CSV and add to a BST?

Comment: @128K: I'm missing _why_ you're making a BST, is it just an exercise?

Comment: It is an exercise to basically play with BST and see how they work